# Beta function in $\lambda_0\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, dimensional-regularization

For a real scalar field $\phi$ after performing all the 1-loop renormalization 
 for dimensional regulator $d = 4 - \epsilon,\ \epsilon \rightarrow 0^+$, I have found that the renormalized coupling $\lambda$ can be related to the bare one by

$$\lambda\Bigg(1 + \frac{3}{(4\pi)^2\epsilon}\lambda_p\Bigg) = \lambda_0 \tag1$$

I'm stuck trying to get the beta function from that equation. We call beta function to

$$\beta(\lambda) = \mu\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial\mu}$$

Taking into account that

$$\lambda = \lambda_p\mu^\epsilon,\qquad [\lambda_p] = 0, \qquad [\mu] = 1$$

My problem is that any way I use to get $\beta(\lambda)$ from Eq. (1) gives a dependence on $\epsilon$, but in Peskin it is used a different way to solve this and the solution is

$$\beta(\lambda) = \frac{3\lambda^2}{(4\pi)^2}$$

How can I get the beta function via Eq. (1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that the bare quantities explicitly do not depend on $\mu$, thus one has the equation
$$
0 = \mu\frac{d \lambda_0}{d\mu} =  \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}+ \beta(\lambda_p)\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda_p}\right)\left(\mu^\epsilon\lambda_p \,Z_\lambda\right)= \epsilon \mu^\epsilon\lambda_p Z_\lambda+\mu^\epsilon \beta(\lambda_p)\frac{d(\lambda_p Z_\lambda)}{d\lambda_p}\,.
$$
Where $$Z_\lambda = 1 + \frac{3\lambda_p}{(4\pi)^2\epsilon}\,.$$
This determines the $\beta$ function as 
$$
\beta(\lambda_p) = - \frac{\epsilon \lambda_p Z_\lambda}{Z_\lambda + \lambda_p\frac{dZ_\lambda}{d\lambda_p}}\,.
$$
Obviously you need to do this perturbatively in $\lambda$, which means that even if $\lambda$ multiplies a pole in $\epsilon$ (which is divergent), you still series expand it as if it was small. If $Z_\lambda \equiv 1 +  \lambda_p^2\,z/\epsilon$ one has
$$
\beta(\lambda_p) = - \frac{\epsilon \lambda_p + z\lambda_p^2}{1+2z\lambda_p/\epsilon} =z \lambda_p^2 +O(\epsilon)= \frac{3\lambda_p^2}{(4\pi)^2}\,.
$$
A consistency check is that the result should never be divergent as $\epsilon \to 0$, this can be proved with the Callan-Symanzik equations.

Comment: I do not understand why you can expand in Taylor series the denominator if that quantity includes a divergence. We are making $(1 + x)^{-1} = 1 - x$ but $x$ diverges while $(1 + x)^{-1} \rightarrow 0$. Is all this method just a trick that we know gives the same result as Callan-Symanzik eqs. or is there something that allows us to make it? I think mathematician wouldn't be happy with this. Of course, thank you for your answer and do not take this as a complaint, I'm just trying to understand it. Thanks!

Comment: This is at the heart of perturbation theory. You have to think the regulator as a finite number throughout all manipulations, and then you are allowed to send it to infinity only in the final expressions where the dependence on the regulator necessarily disappears.

Comment: As for $\lambda$, in perturbation theory any quantity $f(\lambda)$ is though of as a formal power series in $\lambda$:$\sum_k \alpha_k\lambda^k$, which doesn't have to converge (normally one has asymptotic series). If you compute diagrams up to $\ell$ loops you'll obtain an approximate answer $f^{(\ell)}(\lambda)$ which can also be expressed as a formal power series $\sum_k \alpha_k^{(\ell)}\lambda^k$. Perturbation theory tells you that $\alpha_k = \alpha_k^{(\ell)}$ for all $k\leq \ell$ and tells you nothing for the remaining ones. [continues...]

Comment: So when we throw away $\alpha_k^{(\ell)}$ for $k>\ell$ we are just saying that those coefficients are not useful for determining the _true_ coefficients in the power series at this particular order. We are not claiming that they are "small" or "negligible." Hope this makes sense for you.

Comment: I agree with your explanation about the power series on λ but I think that reasoning is only valid if we had developed the denominator of $\beta(\lambda)$ without using the already known Taylor expansion $(1 + x)^r = \sum_n {{r\choose{n}}}x^n$ which is only right for $|x| \ll 1$, i.e., $\lambda_p/\epsilon \ll 1$. If we had done it from pure Taylor series formula (without assuming anything about $x$) I would agree to that expansion in powers of $\lambda$, but the expansion we used in denominator of $\beta$ is restricted to $|x| \ll 1$

Comment: So ok, we can avoid considerations about $\epsilon$ during our calculus but if we make use of something as the usual expansion of $(1 + x)^r$ that introduce restrictions to $x$, we are indirectly imposing conditions on $\epsilon$ from that point on

Comment: I'm not exactly following. But we shouldn't pollute this thread with too many comments. I'd suggest: maybe organize these thoughts and write them up on another question? Perhaps somebody else can help too :)

Comment: Dear MannyC, I have a related question of this post. Could you please check my post here? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/786138/peskin-and-schrorders-qft-eq-12-131-beta-function-of-phi4-theory.