# Taylor expansion in beta function calculation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, dimensional-regularization

This post is related to the answer given in [Beta function in $\lambda_0\phi^4$ theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462605/beta-function-in-lambda-0-phi4-theory)

The beta function calculus for that theory provides you of
$$
\beta(\lambda_p) = - \frac{\epsilon \lambda_p + z\lambda_p^2}{1+2z\lambda_p/\epsilon} =z \lambda_p^2 +O(\epsilon)= \frac{3\lambda_p^2}{(4\pi)^2} \tag1
$$

But right hand side of Eq. (1) is obtained by Taylor expansion of the denominator making use of the already known formula:

$$
(1 + x)^r = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty {{r}\choose {n}}x^n \Leftrightarrow |x| \ll 1, \quad x, r \in \mathbb{R},\quad n\in \mathbb{N} \tag2
$$

But this is only true under the condition $|x| \ll 1$. In Eq. (1), $2z\lambda_p/\epsilon$ plays the role of $x$ in Eq. (2) but due to $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ this quantity is infinite, not less that 1.

I understand that in principle you can make use of Eq. (2) into Eq. (1) because the $\epsilon$ limit is something that you apply only at the end of calculus, but that final result (still $\epsilon$ dependent) will be correct if only if the restriction coming out from Eq. (2) is fullfilled by the $\epsilon$ limit you take because Eq. (2) is only valid in that case. Otherwise, you are mathematically inconsistent and shouldn't use Eq. (2).

Therefore, why can we use (2) in (1)?

Comment: The linked post just gives a squirrelly way to calculated $\beta$.  You can do it perfectly well, using renormalized perturbation theory, without getting that kind of denominator.

Comment: I've seen this kind of computation of the beta function more than once and gives the correct result so there must be a reason. That's what I want to know