# Assumed form for beta function

Tags: gauge-theory, renormalization, yang-mills, unified-theories

In a classical paper on *Hierarchy of Interactions in Unified Gauge Theories*, Georgi et al define the renormalization group equation

$$
\mu \frac{\partial g(\mu)}{\partial \mu } =\beta(g(\mu)).
$$

He then states that (I'm ommiting what I believe to be irrelevant parts about group representation and effective field theory) if $g(\mu)$ is small, then

$$
\beta(g(\mu)) \approx bg(\mu)^3, \,\,\,\,\,\,|g|\ll 1.
$$

Why is this the case? I assume that he is only picking the first term in a expansion of the $\beta$ function on the coupling, but why isn't this first term constant (on $g$), $g$ or $g^2$.

This seems to be tied with the number of points of the interaction (since it would govern the number of factors of $g$ in the loop), but I don't know how to translate it into the $\beta$ function.

Comment: You may have answered your question: perturbation theory. There are two one-loop diagrams correcting the tree-level gluon-fermion-fermion coupling, so providing its variation with scale $\partial g/\partial \mu$, and both are cubic in *g*. Thus the correction to *g* is of order $g^3$. It's possible to rig theories such that this one loop correction vanishes, in which case the surviving β function would be of higher order. Read your QFT texts to follow the detailed calculation.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I see! Because of the same reason we could predict, for instance, that the dominant term of the coupling beta function in $\phi^4$ theory is quadratic -- since the lowest order running correction has two vertices. Right? Thank you!

Comment: [Yes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462605/beta-function-in-lambda-0-phi4-theory).