# Peskin and Schrorder's QFT eq.(12.131), $\beta$ function of $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, renormalization, dimensional-regularization

On Peskin and Schroeder's QFT, page 435, they derived the $\beta$ function for $\phi^4$ theory in a general $d-$dimensional spacetime.

$$\beta=(d-4)\lambda +\beta^{(4)}(\lambda)+\cdots \tag{12.131}$$
where $\beta^{(4)}$ is the four-dimensional result.

While in my personal derivation, $\textbf{I differ a minus sign for the first term}$, where what I obtained is $(4-d)\lambda$. This is the question for this post.

Here is my derivation:

Start from Eq.(12.129)
$$
\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}_0-\frac{1}{2} \rho_m M^2 \phi_M^2-\frac{1}{4} \lambda M^{4-d} \phi_M^4+\cdots \tag{12.129}
$$

We define the dimensional coupling
$$\lambda^\prime =\lambda M^{4-d} $$
The Callan-Symanzik equation should hold in variables of $\lambda^\prime$ (ignore the mass term for a moment)
$$
\left[M \frac{\partial}{\partial M}+\beta(\lambda^\prime) \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda^\prime}+n \gamma(\lambda)\right] G^{(n)}\left(\left\{x_i\right\} ; M, \lambda\right)=0 \tag{12.41}
$$
where
$$\beta(\lambda^\prime)\equiv \frac{M}{\delta M}\delta \lambda^\prime \tag{12.39} $$

Now,
$$\begin{aligned} \delta \lambda^\prime&=(\lambda+\delta \lambda)(M+\delta M)^{4-d}-\lambda^\prime \\ &=(\lambda+\delta \lambda)(M^{4-d}+(4-d)M^{3-d}\delta M+\mathcal{O}(\delta M^2))-\lambda^\prime \\
&=(4-d)\lambda M^{3-d}\delta M+M^{4-d}\delta \lambda 
\end{aligned} \tag{a}$$
then,
$$\begin{aligned} \beta^\prime \frac{\partial }{\partial \lambda^\prime}&=\frac{M}{\delta M}\delta \lambda^\prime \frac{\partial }{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial \lambda^\prime} \\
&=\frac{M}{\delta M}\left((4-d)\lambda M^{3-d}\delta M+M^{4-d}\delta \lambda \right)\frac{1}{M^{4-d}}\frac{\partial }{\partial \lambda} \\
&=\left((4-d)\lambda +\frac{M}{\delta M}\delta \lambda  \right)\frac{\partial }{\partial \lambda}
\end{aligned} \tag{b}$$
So,
$$\beta=(4-d)\lambda+\beta^{(4)}(\lambda) \tag{c}$$
which is $(4-d)\lambda$ instead of $(d-4)\lambda$. So I think I made a mistake somewhere, but I cannot find it out. I would appreciate any answers or comments.

Comment: OP's issue (v1) seems to be a matter of consistently using dimensionful and dimensionless coupling constants in dimensional regularization.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes, exactly! But my result (Eq.(c)) differs a minus sign in the first term with Eq.(12.131). I am troubled for where is my mistake.